# Can i run GTA Vice City on Android-x86 PC?

Tags: android-x86

Recently i have installed Android-x86 on my Lenovo laptop and i want to install and play GTA vice city there. My OS in android 4.4.2. 4 GB ram and 3 GB swap memory 2.4 Ghz quadcore intel i3 processor and nvidia 1 GB video card

Comment: If you install an apk or download it from Google Play, I don't see any reason for it not to run... Does your PC have a touchscreen??

Comment: No thats the problem. I have tried to run temple run but it doesn't run. However angry birds seasons run

Comment: What does the play store app in your laptop show? It will show whether that app you are trying to install is compatible with your device or not.

Comment: I donot have internet access in my  PC. So i want to download the apk through mobile and sideload it

Comment: It probably uses native code compiled for ARM, so it won't work on x86.

Comment: @user110726 it will not w ork that way you need  to download it from the play store

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Or better, set up a dual boot of Windows or Linux ([VC will run](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-225-Grand_Theft_Auto__Vice_City.html) through PlayOnLinux) and play the PC version? It's much better and easier to control. If you don't want to set up a dual boot, you could even boot Windows or Linux from an external HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. It may have some graphical issues considering drivers and probably a few other compatibility problems. The most major spike is the drivers here. If they work and are compatible with game, your game will run. Else it wont (I suspect graphical glitches). Honestly, its almost impossible to judge like that with just that much information provided so that leaves you with only ability to try it and see if it works.

But that aside, how do you plan on playing it? Even if you have/had touch screen I can barely imagine how its possible to play it.

Bottomline-> You can test it. Although I do have doubts in mind that you will be able to play it (not only due to hardware and drivers, but also due to control mechanics).

Comment: I dont have touchscreen.

Comment: Then how do you plan on playing it? Some external controllers?

Comment: yes i want to play it with mouse and keyboard

Comment: I doubt that. It uses touchscreen controls... and there's no way you can emulate touching those specific areas or anything like that using mouse and keyboard. Why not just download GTA Vice City for pc itself?

Comment: but i donot have a windows PC i have installed android on my PC and accidently i have lost all my isos

Comment: Whatever android image you downloaded isnt meant for daily use right now (no current android image is upto that position). So you should immediately uninstall it and download some os like ubuntu instead. Then you can use wine to emulate some windows games (older games like vice city should work). But android on pc isnt meant for daily use, instead just testing and fun purposes. So if you want to experience android on pc, use some virtual workstation like virtual box instead of putting it as only primary os.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure since the official compatible devices is so limited

> **Phones** : Motorola Atrix, Motorola Atrix HD, Motorola Atrix
>   4G, Motorola Photon, HTC Rezound, HTC One X, HTC One X+, Samsung
>   Galaxy Nexus, Samsung Galaxy Note, Samsung Galaxy Note 2, Samsung
>   Galaxy R, Samsung Epic 4G, Samsung Galaxy S2, Samsung Galaxy S3,
>   Google Nexus 4, Sony Xperia Play, Sony Xperia Sola, Sony Xperia S / P
>   / T & TL, Sony Walkman Z Series Media Player
>
> **tablettes** : Acer Iconia, Asus Eee Pad Transformer Prime, Asus
>   Transformer Pad TF300T, Asus Transformer Pad Infinity 700, Motorola
>   Xoom, Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0 / 7.7 / 8.9 & 10.1, Samsung Galaxy Note
>   10.1, Sony Tablet S, Sony Tablet P, Sony Xperia Tablet S, Toshiba Thrive, Toshiba Regza, Google Nexus 7, Google Nexus 10, Fujitsu
>   Stylistic 10.1

[Source](https://goo.gl/7cAFSB)

but if you enter the play store from your laptop (under the android x86 OS) and you can find and install the GTA vice city app it should work just fine if not you can ask for a refund.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the games as you said Temple Run which did not run in your case so as with my prime os when I downloaded it from play store is designed for ARM processor, whereas our PCs have x86 processor{ so is the name android x86}. Just go to apkdl.in and search the game you can change the type to x86 there or just search it typing x86 in the google. Hope u'll find it.